# Using Android's WorkManager to sequentially run a dynamic list of WorkRequests

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist, android-workmanager

I'm trying to learn how to use android's WorkManager with Kotlin but I'm having trouble figuring out how to run a set of requests sequentially from a list of OneTimeWorkRequests where the list does not have a set size.

To start, I have a list of OneTimeWorkRequests that I create with

```
val requestList: MutableList<OneTimeWorkRequest> = ArrayList()
```

Each entry is created and added to this list with something along the lines of:

```
val dataBuilder = Data.Builder()
val data = dataBuilder.putString("key", "data").build()
val request = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MyWorker::class.java).setInputData(data).setInitialDelay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build()
requestList.add(request)
// Each entry has different data and an initial delay
```

I know that, normally, if we want to run work in a sequence with WorkManager, we would do something like:

```
val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(context)
workManager.beginWith(request1).then(request2).then(request3).then(request4).enqueue()
```

But my problem is that the number of requests in the list is not set so the number of "then" calls that I need are not known. I was thinking of creating this list then running through a loop to create the sequence with workManager but this doesn't seem possible since the "beginWith" and "then" calls seem to need to be called all at once. The only thing the MyWorker class does is print out a log with the data so that part is not very complicated at all.

So, is there a way to accomplish this with WorkManager? Or is there perhaps something else I should be using to try and get a sequence of events happen? Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

Check the documentation: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced#chained

Just kidding, but I was able to figure this out by looking at that documentation The important part is hidden in the comments

```
WorkManager.getInstance(myContext)
    .beginWith(workA)
        // Note: WorkManager.beginWith() returns a
        // WorkContinuation object; the following calls are
        // to WorkContinuation methods
    .then(workB)    // FYI, then() returns a new WorkContinuation instance
    .then(workC)
    .enqueue()
```

But that is only part of the way to the answer you want. You'll want to do something like this.

```
val workTaskList: List<WorkRequest> // Some list of tasks
var workContinuation = WorkManager.getInstance(myContext)
    .beginWith(workTaskList[0]) // Ensure 0 is indexable... 
     for(i 1..workTaskList.size) {
       //Make sure you update workContinuation or all the thens won't get enqueued
        workContinuation = workContinuation.then(workTaskList[i])
     }
workContinuation.enqueue()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question with you. Maybe you can make your list task to be static and begin next task when succeed the last one.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my implementation in Java for anyone who needs it

1. Add your `WorkRequests` to a `List` (I used an `ArrayList`)
2. Then build the first `WorkRequest` which will return a `WorkContinuation` object
3. Use that object to queue further `WorkRequest`s which will each return a new `WorkContinuation` object. Each queueing will return a new `WorkContinuation` object to which the next one is added
4. Finally `enqueue()` them.

   ```
    //Add WorkRequest to ArrayList for chaining them
    ArrayList<OneTimeWorkRequest> workRequests = new ArrayList<>();
    int userCount = prefs.getInt("login_accounts", 0);

    //Build and Add all WorkRequests to the ArrayList
    for (int i = 0; i < userCount; i++) {
        Data inputData = new Data.Builder()
                    .putInt("user_id", i)
                    .build();
        OneTimeWorkRequest completeDailySearchesForUser =
                    new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(DailySearches.class)
                            .setConstraints(constraints)
                            .setInputData(inputData)
                            .build();
        workRequests.add(completeDailySearchesForUser);
    }

    // check if you have more than 1 WorkRequest in ArrayList
    if (workRequests.size() > 1) {
        // Add the first one and remove it from ArrayList
        WorkContinuation workContinuation = WorkManager.getInstance(context.getApplicationContext())
                    .beginWith(workRequests.remove(0));

        // Loop over the remaining requests and chain them
        for (OneTimeWorkRequest userWorkRequest : workRequests ) {
                workContinuation = workContinuation.then(userWorkRequest);
        }
        // Finally call enqueue to kick things off
        workContinuation.enqueue();
    } else {
        // If there is only 1 request in list, add a normal request
        // This will ignore calling WorkManager if the list is empty (workRequests.size() = 0)
        if (workRequests.size() == 1) WorkManager.getInstance(context.getApplicationContext())
                    .enqueue(workRequests.get(0));
    }
   ```